# pandas string manipulation with regular expressions

Tags: pandas, regex, string

I have pandas dataframe containing column with string

I want to get read of empty space in the beggining; 1.; 1st and 2nd numbers in a string; also / in the middle of the word, \ between words

I could not remove 2nd digit though

How to do it in one go and also remove second digit in a string
i could do it one by one (not sure if it is correct but working)

```
st={'string':['155555 11111 hhhh 15-0850tcx cord\with plastic end / 
light mustard -82cm  шнур нужд вес 07 кг',' 1. 06900000027899 non woven 
12 grid socks']}
s = pd.DataFrame(st)
s['string'] = s['string'].str.replace(r'\d\.', '') #removes 1. 
s['string'] = s['string'].str.replace(r"\\", " ") #removes backslash
s['string'] = s['string'].str.replace(r"\/", "") #removes backslash
s['string'] = s['string'].str.replace(r"^\d*", "") #removes digit in the begginning of string
s['string'] = s['string'].str.strip() #removes space in front
```

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent of your commands could be:

```
s['string'] = s['string'].str.replace(r'(^\s*\d+\.?\s*|\\|/)', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                                                                                string
0  11111 hhhh 15-0850tcx cordwith plastic end  light mustard -82cm шнур нужд вес 07 кг
1                                               06900000027899 non woven 12 grid socks
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZBJYMi/1)

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your answer. How I can get read of also '11111'  and 06900000027899 so string should start from word

Comment: is there any way to replace also if it starts with 1. and  1) in one go? 
My understanding is that ^\s* - if starts with a spaces until any digit or character; 
.? - dot with any character 
s* - space until any digit. 
Code works but it does not recognise if i have 1) and i do not understand how to combine remove if string starts 1) or1. 
Is there any way it remoes all characters until 1s solid word?
sorry I am new to regex and strings are very dirty

Comment: s['string'] =s['string'].str.replace(r'(^\s*\d+\)?\s*\.?\s*|\\|/)', '', regex=True) - I did that